# Convert string (letter) from file text to integer

Tags: python, string, machine-learning, type-conversion, int

I'm the new one to machine learning. I got some problem when trying to use int for letters. I use Python 3.5 on Mac OS. This is my code:

```
def file2matrix(filename):

    fr = open(filename)
    numberOfLines = len(fr.readlines())
    returnMat = zeros((numberOfLines, 3))
    classLabelVector = []
    fr = open(filename)
    index=0
    for line in fr.readlines():
        line = line.strip()
        listFromLine1 = line.split('\t')
        listFromLine = zeros(3)
        i = 0
        for value in listFromLine1:
            if value.isdigit():
                valueAsInt = int(value)
                listFromLine[i] = valueAsInt
                i += 1
        returnMat[index, :] = listFromLine[0:3]
        classLabelVector.append(int(listFromLine1[-1]))
        index += 1
    return returnMat, classLabelVector
```

This is my txt file:

```
23  8   1   f
7   8   5   j
5   9   1   j
6   6   6   f
```

This is the error:

```
  classLabelVector.append(int(listFromLine1[-1])) ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'f'
```

Can anybody help me with these problems?

Comment: Are you making this file in TextEdit perhaps? The `\\rtf1` looks like a rich text header, such as would be present in a rich text file (which is not the same thing as plain text).

Comment: yeah i did it in TextEdit but then I convert it to .txt already. So can you tell me where should I create my file?

Comment: If you created it to plain text already then the error should be different than what you posted. Is it? If you still see `\\rtf1` in there you probably have not made it pure plain text yet.

Comment: Oh yeah I already convert to plain text as you said, now it returns this error: classLabelVector.append(int(listFromLine1[-1]))                           ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'f'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your desired outcome correctly, you want to return a list with n lists in it. Each list will be along the line of [23. 8. 1.]. Then you want a second list that takes the last number of each list like this: [1, 5, 1, 6].

Assuming this is all correct, the reason you are getting `classLabelVector.append(int(listFromLine1[-1])) ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'f'` is because you are not returning any numbers, but a string instead. I found 3 issues that should fix the error.

First, I found no '\t' in your text document. I instead used `listFromLine1 = line.split(' ')` and it split based on spaces. This could simply be from the way it copied over when you posted, though.

Second, when you assign a value for each position in `listFromLine` you then ignore it and append from `listFromLine1` which you did nothing to, so it remains a string.

Third, try using `if value.isnumeric():` instead of `if value.isdigit():`.

Fixing these few problems should get the program working. Also, you open the file and run fr.readlines() twice and never tell it to close. Your making the program work twice for the same information. You should try to rewrite it to only open once and use `with open() as fr:` because it will close when done.

EDIT: if you want the second list to be the letters instead [f, j, j, f] then keep it as listFromLine1 and use str() instead of int(): `classLabelVector.append(str(listFromLine1[-1]))`

Comment: I mean my listFromLine only contains string (numbers) that have been already converted to int but not letter 'f' and 'j', and I meet error when I tried int('f') so I couldn't include it in listFromLine. However, I want to use integer type of 'f' and 'j' later so I wonder if there was any ways to convert these letter to integer but still display these letter (not number) as an element of classLabelVector.